# Playframework java enums type in form's selects validate as an error.invalid with actual data

Tags: java, forms, validation, playframework, enums

I have an enum:

```
public enum IML {
    VARIANT_I(1, "Wariant I"),
    VARIANT_II(2,  "Wariant II"),
    VARIANT_III(3,  "Wariant III"),
    VARIANT_PREMIUM(4,  "Wariant Premium");

    public int id;
    public String name;

    IML(int id, String name) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }
    public static Map<String, String> getOptions() {
        LinkedHashMap<String, String> options = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();
        for (IML e: IML.values()) {
            options.put(String.valueOf(e.id), e.name);
        }
        return options;
    }
}
```

Which I put into Select helper in view layer:

```
@select(
        imlForm("variant"),
        options(IML.getOptions()),
        '_label -> "Variant"
)
```

And validate in controller:

```
public static Result submit{} {
    ...
    System.out.println(form.field("variant").value());
    System.out.println(form);
    ...
}
```

When I left this select field blank is ok, But When I choose any option I am getting validation error:

```
errors={variant=[ValidationError(variant,error.invalid,[])]})
```

When I print this field in console I am getting integer number that equals to `<select><options value=""` parameter.

I am doing something wrong. Can Anyone point me this out? Shouldn't play automatically bind value from form to correct enum? Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured this out on my own. Play bind enum on its name,  not  any custom parameter. So I need to change this line:

```
        options.put(String.valueOf(e.id), e.name);
```

into

```
        options.put(String.valueOf(e.name()), e.name);
```

where method `name()` is declared on `java.lang.Enum` class